# Php array post values difficulties

Tags: php, arrays, variables, post, checkbox

I can't seem to understand why I cant pass any values with the following code:

```
<div class="menu">
Por favor seleccione os conteúdos:
<form name="Categorias" action="Elementos_Descritivos.php" method="post">
<?php 

$Categorias = array ("Nome", "Data", "Cliente", "Observacoes");

 foreach( $Categorias as $key => $value){

echo "<div class=\"cb-row\">
      <label for=\"$value\">$value:</label>
      <input id=\"$value\" $value=\"$value\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"$value\" checked />
      </div>";
}
 ?>
   <div class="submit">
    <input type="submit" value="Seguinte" />
</div>
    </form>
</div>
 </div>
```

In the Elemento_Descritivos.php page All the code i have is:

```
<?php

 print("<pre>");
 print_r($_POST);
 print("</pre>");

?>
```

It simply outputs:

Array
(
)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set the **name** attribute on all your inputs for a form post to work. The **ID** is not posted when a form is submitted.

```
 <input id=\"$value\" name=\"$value\" .../>
```

Do the same for your submit button. It will allow you to figure out which submit button was pressed in case you have many in the same form.

Comment: When the servers outputs to the browse what im effectively getting is name="Nome" is it not? When it was all plain html it worked flawlessly, do you mean that my submit button needs a "name" argument?

Comment: I just have this one form, its all I got on that page. Hence why im still confused on this issue, im sorry but could you please explain a bit further? Thank you.

Comment: Look at the HTML you're outputting - you'll end up with Nome="Nome" instead of name="Nome"

Comment: I do get Nome="Nome" but why is that stopping me from seeing anything when i post to the next page since im trying to see all of the values in $_POST, this might sound stupid but im really hitting a wall on this one. Thanks

Comment: -_- duh! Sorry everyone I got it... Thank you all for your time, I deserve pain in coders hell.

Answer (score 2):

As Wadih pointed out - you need to assign a name attribute to your inputs.  I've rewritten your code in hopes it becomes a little more clear what is going on.  I've also removed the attribute $value=\"$value\".

```
<div class="menu">
    Por favor seleccione os conteúdos:
    <form name="Categorias" action="Elementos_Descritivos.php" method="post">

    <?php 
    $Categorias = array ("Nome", "Data", "Cliente", "Observacoes");
    foreach( $Categorias as $category){
    ?>

    <div class="cb-row">
        <label for="<?=$category;?>">
            <?=$category;?>
        </label>
        <input
            id="<?=$category;?>"
            name="<?=$category;?>"
            type="checkbox"
            value="<?=$category;?>"
            checked
            />
    </div>

    <?
    } //foreach
    ?>

    <div class="submit">
        <input name="categories" type="submit" value="Seguinte" />
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I feel pretty dumb as it was quite clear in the first post. I appreciate you taking your time to rewrite the code its quite interesting to see different approaches :)

Comment: Happy to help, lets me procrastinate from doing what I should be doing while feeling like I've done something :)

Comment: Eddy, remove the top '<?php' and bottom '?>' tags that surround your markup, as you can't directly put html markup in a php codeblock. The example you posted won't work.

Comment: oops, didn't notice the extra tags in there, removed them for posterity.